# How can I perform multi-group SEM in R with different items for each group and different sample sizes?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, mediation

The setting would be appropriate for an Item-Response Theory model; however, I'd like to perform mediation analysis. The problem is that there are some pairs of items that do not have any group in common, leading to missing values in the covariance matrix even if pairwise deletion is used. This implies that (within the "lavaan" routine):

1) Factor-score regression (the "fsr" command) doesn't work: since the covariance matrix is used to derive factors, missing values ("NA" in the matrix) make it non-reversable.

2) A multi-group analysis doesn't work as well, as long as all items are expected to be measured in each group (in this case, all groups will have items not available for anyone, unless some groups include all items).

What I've been able to do so far is a SEM analysis using the data and not sample covariances and means. If I well understand, the problem of the impossibility of estimating a covariance matrix is overcome in this way by assuming observed variables are given (so, given no error is implied, talking about the error structure makes no sense). However I guess that ignoring the information of the group each observation belongs to leads to biased estimates.

Please correct me if what I stated above is wrong.
My question is: **how can I do multi-group SEM analysis in R by allowing for both a different (but possibly overlapping) set of observed variables for each group, and for different group sizes?**

Comment: What is the reason that some observed variables were measured in one group and not the other? I ask not to criticize, but rather, because depending on the rationale, there may be a relatively straightforward solution.

Comment: It is a meta-analysis in which a different set of items was measured in each study. Item-response theory was already performed in order to build the latent factors, but now we are trying to see whether mediation analysis is feasible.

Comment: Can you model the data as a mimic model rather than as multiple groups?

Comment: I think the mediator could be modeled as MIMIMC (affected by the treatment and measured by its related items) but I'm not sure for the outcome (since it's not only affected by the treatment, but also by another latent factor, i.e. the mediator). Also, I don't see how this should solve my multi-group problem (i.e. the fact that each group has a different set of items to measure the latent factors, and some pairs of items - even those measuring the same latent factors - are never present together, since no group has both).